# File output into an array using bash

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I have sorted (descending) output in a file in table format from a query I did using aws CLI. I need to take a field from the output file and present all unique lines as an option for user to choose from. Here is an example of output file:

```
Description        Snapshot             StartTime
Volume0            snap-x123456789      2020-04-22T20:55:10
Volume10           snap-y123456789      2020-04-22T20:45:09
Volume12           snap-a123456789      2020-04-22T20:40:08
Volume15           snap-b123456789      2020-04-22T20:35:07
Volume0            snap-c123456789      2020-04-22T20:30:06
Volume10           snap-d123456789      2020-04-22T20:25:05
```

The goal is to present all volumes after reading above output and prompt user to enter volume number OR user can enter A for ALL so that system can restore the snapshot(s) for that volume. Something like this:

```
0 - Volume0
10 - Volume10
12 - Volume12
15 - Volume15
```

Here is what I have, how can I get the user to enter a number corresponding to the volume number or enter ALL to restore all? Should I be using an array for from the output file? How can I do this efficently?

```
output() {

    echo "Here is a list of volumes found in $region"

    for DR in (grep Volume# "$input" | top -n 1)
    do 
    echo $DR
    done

    echo "Hello, please tell me what Volume you are searching for..(Volume?):"
    read volSearch

    echo -e "Searching for newest SnapshotIds in region using output file GetfileSnapId for:\n" $volSearch
    echo
    sleep 5
    input="/Users/user/Downloads/GetfileSnapId"


    if x=$(grep -m 1 "$volSearch" "$input")
    then
        echo
        echo "$x"
    else
        echo
        echo "$volSearch not found..ending search"
    fi

    extractSnap=$(echo "$x" | cut -d'|' -f2 )

    echo
    echo $extractSnap

    regionoutput=$(echo "$extractSnap" | awk '{print $4}' )
    echo
    echo "$regionoutput"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the bash select command.

I put the following into a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

options=($(tail +2 t.txt | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort | uniq) Quit)

PS3='Please enter your choice: '
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    echo $opt

    if [ $opt = "Quit" ]
    then
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: Hi - thank you Richard. How can I read output from file (GetfileSnapId) into select command and a array? I would like to use output from any aws region and present it for user to select any of the volumes or select all volumes.

Comment: I see your problem.  Working it.